# Common values in 2 columns in 2 files

Tags: awk

Suppose I have these 2 tab delimited files, where the second column in first file contains matching values from first column of the second file, I would like to get an output like this:

FileA:

```
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

FileB:

```
A    Apple
C    Cinnabon
B    Banana
```

I would like an output like this:

```
1   Apple
2   Banana
3   Cinnabon
```

I can write a script for this, but I would like to know how to make it in `awk` or `perl` in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you want is this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{$2=a[$2]; print}' file2 file1
1 Apple
2 Banana
3 Cinnabon
```

Comment: why are you doing `a[$1]=$2 FS $3` file2 only has two fields so you are just concatenating an empty string and you don't handle `OFS`. What you want is `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}{print a[$1],$2}' OFS='\t' file1 file2`

Comment: With `OFS` you're setting a new delimiter which you don't actually need to do, it's already space delimited, why change that unless you need to? `$2=a[$2]` sets the second field of the first file to the second field to the second. Both mine and your answer are equally as valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2=a[$2]}1' f2 f1
```

Answer (score 1):

### GNU sed oneliner

```
sed -r 's:\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+):/\\s*\\S\\+\\s\\+\1/s/\\(\\s*\\S\\+\\s\\+\\)\1/\\1\2/:' fileB | sed -f - fileA
```

..output:

```
1    Apple
2    Banana
3    Cinnabon
```